# create query with array parameter

Tags: symfony, doctrine-odm

I try to execute this query

```
$em->createQuery('select i from AcmePublicBundle:Public i where i.user in (:opc)');
$query->setParameter('opc', $opc);

where :opc is an array like this
$opc={array}[2]
  0 = {array}[1]
     id = "9"
  1 = {array}[1] 
     id = "10"
```

I get this error

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in...
```

If I try this

```
$em->createQuery('select i from AcmePublicBundle:Public i where i.usuario in (9, 10)');
```

everything is fine. But I have to pass `$opc`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, error seems quite appropriate because `setParameter` takes both `array` key and value into account and key represents field name. Therefore, you can't use matrix here.

```
$ids = array();
foreach ( $opc as $o ){
    $ids[] = (int)$o[1]; //be careful about data type (string, int etc)
}
$q = " .... WHERE id IN (:opc) ... ";
$q->setParameter('opc', $ids);
```

This should work....

Answer (score 1):

Your `$opc` array should not be multidimensional. Try passing an array like this:

```
$opc=array(
  '9',
  '10'
);
```

instead of

```
$opc=array(
  array('id'=>'9'),
  array('id'=>'10')
);
```